# jQuery Touch Events within .on?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, mobile, touch

Is there any way to bind mobile touch events such as touchstart to the jQuery .on() method?

I currently have a drag and drop selection area application I have developed, which detects click and drag movements as so:

```
$('.foo').on({
    mousedown: function(e){
        ...
    }
});
```

I know you can bind these to handle the events, but it would be useful to even combine the equivalent event (touchstart > mousedown) somehow, would this even be possible just to trigger the mousedown event in a bind for the touchstart event?

Comment: `$('.foo').on('mousedown touchstart')` ?

Comment: Can you combine it with the function so it does the same thing, rather than me having to specify it separately?

Comment: @drys above, not sure if it notifies you without a mention.

Comment: `$('.foo').on('mousedown touchstart', function(){//something})` you mean this? The function will get called both on touchstart and mousedown.

Comment: I believe I need it within the array structure I have specified, since I have also mousemove and mouseup, to all trigger as a drag selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be what you need. Note that in the `mousemove` handler you need to know if the mouse button is down at the moment (can be achieved with setting a boolean variable in start/end event handlers).

```
function handleEventStart(e){
  //something
}

function handleEventMove(e){
  //something
}

function handleEventEnd(e){
  //something
}

var $foo = $('.foo');
$foo.on('mousedown touchstart', handleEventStart);
$foo.on('mousemove touchmove', handleEventMove);
$foo.on('mouseup touchend touchcancel', handleEventEnd);
```

Comment: This seems like the easiest option, thank you. Just tested and everything seems to work equivalently.